# Match seven columns for each record using regex

Tags: regex, vba

I have tried to simulate a regex pattern on the following link
https://regex101.com/r/yusSo4/1

It works partially, as I need to get 7 columns for each record
Group 3 should be separated to be two groups

[image]

This is my try but this is not totally correct

```
^( *\d{6,12} *\n)(.*\n(?:.*\n)?)( *\d{14} *\n)( *\d{14} *\n)(.*\n(?:.*\n)?)( *\d{1,2} *\n)(.*\n(?:.*\n)?)((?:\n(?! *\d{6,10} *$)[^\d\n]+)*)
```

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew The main pattern was for you. Can you have a look, please?

Comment: @ works only when the person is already involved in the topic.

Comment: @braX The topic needs someone expert at regex. The pattern is already there, it just needs some modifications.

Comment: I understand, I was just making you aware that Wiktor will not be "pinged" or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I can work around the pattern to get the desired results

```
^( *\d{6,12} *\n)(.*\n(?:.*\n)?)( *\d{14} *\n)( *\d{14} *\n)(.*\n(?:.*\n)?)( *\d{1,2} *\n)(.*\n?)((?:\n(?! *\d{6,10} *$)[^\d\n]+)*)
```

But I welcome any other suggestions